documentation for Interop.QBXMLRP2 - QuickBooks ask for C#
I need to work on old system of QuickBooks Desktop integration using C# and in that the company has used Interop.QBXMLRP2 for inserting data into the QuickBooks.
Now I am tasked with making programs to get data from the QB with this and I need proper documentation for it.
I tried looking on the internet but could not find any documentation that would help me write the data query code in C# using Interop.QBXMLRP2.
Please help me out with it. Thank you in advance.
